# TSQL - search multiple columns for single value

Tags: t-sql, barcode

Our database has the following item information:

```
ItemNumber | ItemDescription | CaseUPC        | BoxUPC         | UnitUPC
===============================================================================
12345      | Widget          | 00487060982629 | 00334556905837 | 00803709021138
23456      | Dunkit          | 00442765157512 | 00688083046260 | 00148006723652
34567      | Tiklet          | 00671178066801 | 00181369288501 | 00371783583016
```

We receive customer information that quite often looks like this:

```
ItemNumber | UPC
=========================
XPQR       | 487060982629
ROFL       | 688083046260
WTAF       | 371783583016
LOLBBQ     | 123456789012
```

Because most of our customers are not computer literate, and use Excel to create the CSV files they send us, the leading zeros for the UPC codes are missing, yet they are valid codes.

Using SQL Server 2012, my task is to match the UPC code provided by the customer against our Item table to produce a report that looks like this:

```
CustomerItemNumber | OurItemNumber | OurItemDescription | MatchMethod
======================================================================
XPQR               | 12345         | Widget             | CaseUPC
ROFL               | 23456         | Dunkit             | BoxUPC
WTAF               | 34567         | Tiklet             | UnitUPC
LOLBBQ             | --            | --                 | no match found
```

I tried using multiple LEFT JOINS from the customer item table to our item table:

```
SELECT C.ItemNumber,
        O.ItemNumber, 
        O.ItemDescription,
        O.CaseUPC,
        O.BoxUPC,
        O.UnitUPC
FROM CustomerItemTable C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OurItemTable O ON RIGHT('000000000000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(C.UPC)), 12) = RIGHT('000000000000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(O.CaseUPC)), 12)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OurItemTable O2 ON RIGHT('000000000000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(C.UPC)), 12) = RIGHT('000000000000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(O2.BoxUPC)), 12)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OurItemTable O3 ON RIGHT('000000000000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(C.UPC)), 12) = RIGHT('000000000000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(O3.UnitUPC)), 12)
```

...but I end up with duplicate records

Comment: is UPC always a numeric value? or would/could it include characters as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you are joining the same table over and over again - you can use a single join with a condition on multiple columns.
Also, you can simply get rid of all leading zeros by casting to int:

```
SELECT C.ItemNumber,
        O.ItemNumber, 
        O.ItemDescription,
        O.CaseUPC,
        O.BoxUPC,
        O.UnitUPC
FROM CustomerItemTable C
LEFT OUTER JOIN OurItemTable O 
ON CAST(C.UPC AS int) IN(CAST(O.CaseUPC AS INT), CAST(O.BoxUPC AS INT), CAST(O.UnitUPC AS INT))
```

That is, of course, assuming you want to join the tables if the UPC on the CustomerItemTable matches any of CaseUPC, BoxUPC or UnitUPC on OurItemTable.

Comment: UPC is not an integer -- it has digits but should be represented as treated as a string IMO

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled, that's what I was looking for (slight modifications on my end, of course).

Comment: @Hogan while correct, I've only suggested the conversion to int to eliminate the need to refer to the leading zeroes when comparing the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column only has numeric data, convert it in the join:

```
... CONVERT(INT, UPC) ...
```

Otherwise, use LIKE instead of equals:

```
... LIKE upc + '%' ...
```

Also, you should probably join the table only once, using multiple WHERE-clauses instead.